# getting last row from each id and compare it with count

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i have a table with message infos in postgresql database. Each message has its own id and version number (1, 2, 3, etc.) but it can happen that some version will be missing so there will be messages with versions 1, 2, 4, 5, etc.
What i need to do is find out how many messages are missing their version number. I wrote a code

```
select id_msg, count(version)
    from message
    group by id_msg
    having count(version) = (
    select version
    from message
    order by version desc
    limit 1
    );
```

but its not a proper solution because i dont know how to insert the message id (which is currently being checked) into the subquery. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method to identify missing versions:

```
select id_msg
from message m
group by id_msg
having count(*) <> max(version);
```

You can then count these with a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select id_msg
      from message m
      group by id_msg
      having count(*) <> max(version)
     ) m;
```

Comment: oh, max() is the solution, i completely forgot about that.. thank you a lot!